# Quit Java Program After all Threads Have Completed

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime

I have a password saving program that saves passwords to a text file. The user can add or delete passwords and the data will be re-written to the text file. To prevent the program from being really slow, I create a new thread every time the program needs to save. I have a class that extends Thread and will write all data to the text file specified. The problem I am having is when I try to save all data before the user wants to quit. When the quit button is pressed I create a new thread to save the data and then call the System.exit() function to quit.

```
Thread t = new SaveThread();
t.start();
System.exit(0);
```

I have noticed that the program will quit before the thread completes. Is there any way that I can tell java to only quit when my thread has stopped running?

Comment: You can call `t.join()` before the exit of course.

Comment: do not set "daemon" flag for your threads, and JVM will wait for completion of all background threads.

Comment: Why is it so slow saving a text file ? THat's the first question that comes to my mind

Comment: @Gray: You may post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @jdevelop The problem only occurs when there are 10+ passwords, at 5 lines each password so 50 lines of text that needs to be written. I guess the program quits just before all lines can be written.

Comment: Again, JVM waits for ALL threads to complete. If you don't face something in files - then perhaps you're not flushing streams. Or threads are in daemon mode.

Comment: If the program finished just from reaching the end of the main method then yes, the JVM would wait for all non-daemon threads to be finished. But since I was calling 'System.exit(0)' to finish the JVM did not wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Call [`t.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) after you start the thread
2. Use [`t.run()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) instead of [`t.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)
3. Add your save thread as a shutdown hook via [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

**Option 1**

This one is easy:

```
Thread t = new SaveThread();
t.start();
t.join();
System.exit(0);
```

**Option 2**

Also easy:

```
Thread t = new SaveThread();
t.run();
System.exit(0);
```

**Option 3**

Also easy, but is done when your application is starting. In your app initialization code, do this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new SaveThread());
```

And it will run automatically when the application is closing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Runtime.addShutdownHook()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to register code that should be run before the JVM shuts down.

OR

You can use `Thread.join()` to wait for a thread.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. Before calling `System.exit()`, call `thread.join()` on each of your threads.
2. Instead of calling `System.exit()`, let your main thread return from its `main()` function. This will wait for all non-daemon threads to terminate before the process is shut down.

Answer (score 0):

If the `SaveThread` is the last action to perform, why not moving the `System.exit()` call into that thread?

---

There are better solutions, agreed, but if you wanted to use this approach and use instances of this save thread multiple times, then you could easily parameterize it:

```
public SaveThread extends Thread {

   private exitAfterSave = false;

   public SaveThread() {
     this(false);
   }

   public SaveThread(boolean exitAfterSave) {
     this.exitAfterSave = exitAfterSave;
   }

   @Overwrite
   public void run() {

      // Save what has to be saved

      if (exitAfterSave) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: because the save thread is called many times throughout the program when I do not want the program to quit.